# How to deploy a cloud function on parse server

Tags: deployment, parse-server

After I update the list of cloud functions, I have to completely reboot the server to make the functions available. Is there a more convenient way to update your cloud features list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment no, the cloud functions are directly injected into parse-server runtime to guaranteed the maximum performance.